# Where is my mistake in extracting percentages for Urban Atlas 2018 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, atlas

When extracting percentages for Urban atlas and adding up all the percentages for one address I either end up at ~60% (80 percent of the times) and also sometimes at 120% (the remaining 20%). Do you know what I am doing wrong? Here is what I did:

I have the x/y coordinates of addresses in GB, Germany and Ireland and downloaded the 2018 versions of Urban Atlas (all cities for Ireland, Germany and GB). I included the addresses by the step "add delimited text layer" and made buffers with the radius of 200m, 500m, 1km and 2km (using MMQGIS). I merged all Urban atlas pieces to one big map. Then I reprojected both layers to EPSG:3035. I made a new variable in the buffer shapefiles called "catchArea" that included the $area of the current buffer. Then I intersected the buffer-shapefile with the all-in-one UA-map. After that step I made a new variable in the intersected file with `$area` (called classArea) and then made another variable with the formula: `(classArea/catchArea)*100`.

Now adding up all the percentages I don't end up at 100% as it should be. This error does not exist if I have a buffer with a radius of 10m but I do not get less percentages with the 2km buffer. (So it is 60% in 200m and 60% in 2km most of the times).

I now started to make an extra step with dissolving the all-in-one map first and now intersect it. Dissolving worked fine but intersection now runs for 5 days now and there is no end in sight. Even if this is my solution it takes too long to be a solution and I am hoping for your swarm intelligence to tell me where I have made a mistake.

Comment: how did you "Then I reprojected both layers to EPSG:3035."? - what projection(s) were they in before?

Comment: I used "reproject layer" in the processing toolbox. The projection for the buffers were EPSG:4362 and the CRS for the Urban atlas was:"Project CRS: unknown CRS:Projcrs ...".

Comment: you can't make KM buffers with degree data (4326)

Comment: Ok great, thanks! So I reproject the urban atlas to 4362 and leave the buffer at that crs and my problem should be solved? Or won't that work as I can't have urban atlas as degree data?

Comment: No, you need to make your buffers in a projected CRS such as 3035 - preferably for all the layers

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. You mean that I first make the reprojection to 3035  and then the buffers with the reprojected file?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you end up with all the world when you make a 200 degree buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved. Here is what I did wrong and how to solve it (thanks again to Ian Turton for pointing it out!).

What I did wrong: I first added the xy coordinates with delimited text layer. Here I used the default projection of 4326. Then I made the buffers. As Ian Turton pointed out this did not work as I can't make km buffers around degree data (it seems 4326 is degree data, which I did not know).

How it is solved: I now added the xy coordinates with delimited text layer. Here I used the default projection of 4326 again. But now I reproject the addresses to crs:3035 and then made my buffers. The rest stayed the same.

Thank you very much for your time to read my problem and suggesting solutions to it. Special thanks to Ian Turton for pointing out the crs-problem.